# Python .index() Function not Working in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Following a tutorial and this program won't run as expected

```
my_tuple = {'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'}

print(my_tuple.index('p'))
```

Whenever I run this program, the terminal always outputs:

```
    print(my_typle.index('p'))
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Does VS Code's Python not run these functions or, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) So, `set` doesn't have a method called `index`.

Comment: That's not a tuple.  It's a set.  Tuples use parentheses  `( )`, not curly braces `{ }`.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `my_tuple = {'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'}`, exactly what do you expect this to mean? Specifically, what do you expect is the effect of the `{` and `}` brackets? In your own words, what is a *tuple*, and how should it be written? Where the error message says `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'index'`, what do you think this means? Specifically, why do you suppose it says `'set' object`, and **does not** say `'tuple' object`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's not a tuple, it's a set. A tuple uses Parentheses and an set uses Curly Brackets.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_set.asp

Proper code:

```
my_tuple = ('a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e')

print(my_tuple.index('p'))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer], and do not attempt to answer questions that are caused by a typo and/or do not show any evidence of attempting to read or understand the error message.

Comment: Thank you! I accidentally confused the parentheses for curly brackets.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to access `index` method of `set` object, which does not exist. You should create a `list` object instead:

```py
my_tuple = ['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']

print(my_tuple.index('p'))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer], and do not attempt to answer questions that are caused by a typo and/or do not show any evidence of attempting to read or understand the error message. (Also, Python has a `tuple` type as well as `list`, which would work just as well here; and that's presumably what OP intended to create, given the variable name.)